# Why are my Desandro Masonry blocks vertically overlapping with bootstrap columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I am trying to set up Desandro's Masonry on my site, but it's not working out so far.  I want to use bootstrap columns and thumbnails to display my images.  The problem is that the columns are overlapping vertically.  The masonry script appears to be changing the height of the grid to approximately 400 pixels, which is not right considering I have 9 thumbnails.  Anyone have any ideas?

My HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-sm-4 grid-item">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="{img_url}" rel="lightbox"><img src="{img_url}" alt="Filipino Moon Rise" data-image-url="{img_url}" /></a>
      <div class="thumbnail-caption">
        <h3>Filipino Moon Rise</h3>
        <p>A beautiful moon rise over the South China Sea.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-image-url]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('image-url'));
  })

    $('.grid').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
});
</script>
```

My CSS:

```
.row > .grid.item > .thumbnail {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    padding: 15px;
    border: 0;
    color: #fff;
}
.grid {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

This is my result:
[image]

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Don't use the bootstrap grid with masonry. Masonry is going to apply it's own layout engine.